# Connection Pooling with NEST ElasticSearch Library

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, elasticsearch, nest

I'm currently using the NEST ElasticSearch C# Library for interacting with ElasticSearch. My project is an MVC 4 WebAPI project that basically builds a RESTful webservice for accessing directory assistance information.

We've only just started working with NEST, and have been stumbling over the lack of documentation. What's there is useful, but it's got some very large holes. Currently, everything we need works, however, we're running into an issue with connections sometimes taking up to a full second. What we'd like to do is use some sort of connection pooling, similar to how you'd interact with SQL Server.

Here is the documentation on how to connect using nest: http://mpdreamz.github.com/NEST/concepts/connecting.html

Here is the relevant code snippet from our project:

```
public class EOCategoryProvider : IProvider
{
    public DNList ExecuteQuery(Query query)
    {
        //Configure the elastic client and it's settings
        ConnectionSettings elasticSettings = new ConnectionSettings(Config.server, Config.port).SetDefaultIndex(Config.index);
        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(elasticSettings);

        //Connect to Elastic
        ConnectionStatus connectionStatus;
        if (client.TryConnect(out connectionStatus))
        {
            // Elastic Search Code here ...
        } // end if
    } // end ExecuteQuery
} // end EOCategoryProvider
```

From looking at the documentation, I can't see any provisions for a connection pool. I've been thinking about implementing my own (having, say 3 or 4 ElasticClient objects stored, and selecting them round-robin style), but I was wondering if anyone had a better solution. If not, does anyone have advice on the best way to implement a connection pool by hand? Any articles to point to?

Thanks for anything you guys come up with.

**Update**: This seems to have been related to calling TryConnect on every request, and the particular network setup. The problem completely disappeared when using a machine on the same network as the Elastic box; My development machine (which averages 350ms to the Elastic box) seemed to fail to make http connections sometimes, which caused the long times in TryConnect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't have to call `TryConnect()` each time you do a call to Elasticsearch.  It's basically a sanity check call for when your application starts.

NEST is the C# REST client for Elasticsearch and the default `IConnection` uses `WebRequest.Create` which already pools TCP connections.

Review the actual implementation: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Connection/HttpConnection.cs

Reusing `ElasticClient` won't offer any performance gains since each call already gets its own  `HttpWebRequest`. The whole client is built stateless on purpose.

I am however very interested in why calls are taking 1 second for you. Could you post the actual NEST code, how you are are measuring the calls and describe your data.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of NEST.

Comment: Yeah that be great. I'd like to get to something reproducable and some data on the call i.e it took X ammount of time but if i fire it using something like fiddler it takes Y ammount of time. Try starting fiddler alongside when you run the code so you can easily replay it. (search might be cached on elasticsearch's side so be careful with false positives)

Comment: I was mistakenly informed by our Elastic guru that NEST used a binary protocol, hence my desire to pool the connections.

The use of TryConnect now makes more sense (just checking to make sure your settings are correct) but the documentation isn't entirely clear about that point.

As for why it was taking a second, it seems (somehow) related to the network. A machine in the same datacenter never has issues. I was using Stopwatch to measure, and all the time seemed to be in the TryConnect call. My average ping time to the Elastic box (on the machine exhibiting the problem) is 350ms.

Comment: Sorry, was having trouble with the comment system. Accidentally posted before I was done.

Comment: I'm egotistically glad to hear it was a machine in your cluster acting up. Thank you for updating the question! Always nice for googlers who'll skim this post in the future. Stay in touch if you have any problems/questions/requests the best way is by posting to github issues.