# elasticsearch through NEST: what is the recommended way to connect to a cluster of several hosts

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm starting to work with NEST.
I've seen in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334717/connection-pooling-with-nest-elasticsearch-library) that I should use TryConnect only once at the beginning of the program and then use Connect.
But that seems a bit too naive for a long running system.
What if I have a cluster of say 3 machines and I want to make sure I can connect to any of the 3 machines?
What should be the recommended way of doing that?

Should I:
- Use TryConnect each time and use a different host + port if it fails (downside - an additional roundtrip each time)?
- Try to work with a client and have some retry mechanism to handle failures due to connectivity issues? Maybe implement a connection pool on top of that?

Any other option?
Any suggestions/recommendations?
Sample code?

Thanks for your help,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

Connection pooling is an often requested feature, but due to the many heuristics involved and different approaches NEST does not come with this out of the box. You will have to implement this yourself.

I would not recommend calling `TryConnect()` before each call as now you are doing two calls instead of one.

Each NEST call returns a [IResponse](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/Domain/Responses/BaseResponse.cs) which you can check for `IsValid`, `ConnectionStatus` will hold the request and response details.

See also the documentation on [handling responses](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/concepts/handling-responces.html)

In 1.0 NEST will start to throw an exception incase of TCP level errors so more generic approaches to connection pooling can be implemented, and nest might come with a separate nuget package implementing one (if anything as reference). See also this discussion https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/pull/224#issuecomment-16347889

Hope this helps for now.

**UPDATE** this answer is outdated NEST 1.0 ships with connection pool and cluster failover support out of the box: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/cluster-failover.html